# OData from .Net application ends with Unauthorized

Tags: c#, odata, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to consume the new Dynamics AX OData endpoint from a .Net console applications, I can see that the authentication is going fine but whenever I try to get the results on my application it ends with an Unauthorized error.
Any idea on what could be the cause or hos to get a more detailed information (logs)?

This is the code that throws the error at line:

foreach (var legalEntity in context.Teams.AsEnumerable())

```
static void Main(string[] args)
       {
       Uri oDataUri = new Uri(ODataEntityPath, UriKind.Absolute);
       var context = new Resources(oDataUri);

       context.SendingRequest2 += new EventHandler<SendingRequest2EventArgs>(delegate (object sender, SendingRequest2EventArgs e)
        {
          var authenticationHeader = OAuthHelper.GetAuthenticationHeader();
          e.RequestMessage.SetHeader(OAuthHelper.OAuthHeader, authenticationHeader);
         });

     foreach (var legalEntity in context.Teams.AsEnumerable())
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", legalEntity.Name);
     }

     Console.ReadLine();
```

**Exception**

```
at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)

   Unauthorized

   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute()
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at ODataConsoleApplication.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

**Auth logs**

```
Activated   Event   Time    Duration    Thread
    06/04/2016 9:55:13: 42dbc15a-e068-4f46-9e99-3e41b1820eb9 - AcquireTokenHandlerBase: === Token Acquisition finished successfully. 
    An access token was retuned:
    Access Token Hash: UsxaQ/QZQ+opGz/PC55O5cWYBV8kh1uhvf/CG269WSc=
    Refresh Token Hash: 8aKSzBXtBrxr+uVaqhnT/IEg1+gXOkDqq/WHp8SmaBk=
    Expiration Time: 06/04/2016 10:55:12 +00:00
    User Hash: f1MLHm5K8HDY7tRpkz4amU2+CVFL53JJq3Ybc5q53g0= 4.59s       

Activated   Event   Time    Duration    Thread
    Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException' in Microsoft.OData.Client.dll 
    ("An error occurred while processing this request.")    5.13s       [18036] <No Name>
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the HTTP requests using a web debugger like Fiddler?

Comment: Did you ever get a response to this? I've just hist exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You must add your application in Dynamics in order for it to work.

See ​System administration > Setup > Azure Active Directory applications